# C++ special-value-type loop has to exit when a negative value is entered without using break statement

Tags: c++

I just completed a program that has to quit when a negative value is entered as input. Everything is working good except for only one issue, it quits the program after the second time a negative value is entered. After some research I noticed the use of break, however the samples I have to guide the assignment use only if and else statement.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
// insert code here...
// create a variable named "pounds" that can be used to store an integer.
// wait for the user to type in a value and put that value into the variable ounces
{
    int poundsTotal;
    int ouncesTotal;


    while (poundsTotal >= 0)
    {
        cout << "Enter pounds or a negative number to quit: ";
        cin >> poundsTotal;
        ouncesTotal = poundsTotal * 16;
        cout << poundsTotal << " pouds is " << ouncesTotal << " ounces."  <<endl;
        cout << " Enter pounds or a negative number to quit ";
        cin >> poundsTotal;
        poundsTotal++;
    }
    if (poundsTotal == 0){
        cout <<"you enter a zero value" <<"Try onemore time";
    }
    else {
        cout << "you chose to quit the program" <<poundsTotal;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you've not already done so, learn to use a debugger and step through your program one line at a time. Before running a line in the debugger, try to figure out what the line will do and how it will change your variables. Then run the line and verify that the variables do change in ways you think they should. If they do not, try to figure out why not. Doing this over and over again will help you understand programming better and solve problems faster. If you do not have access to a debugger, try using [Rubber Duck Debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Answer (score 0):

The condition of a while loop is evaluated after the body has been executed. Then it is determined whether the body will be run again. Change your code and add an if statement inside the loop.

```
if(poundsTotal < 0) break;
```

And yes, a break statement is useful in a loop. Otherwise you can't stop the loop before your test condition is evaluated to false.
In your case, I find using a break would be a simple option.

Comment: Ah yes that's a more suitable word.

Answer (score 0):

When the program first reaches `while (poundsTotal >= 0)`, `poundsTotal` has no defined value. This puts you at the mercy of the gods as to whether the program will work as expected or not, and Gods are notoriously unreliable. For more information, look up the term Undefined Behaviour.

The solution to this is ask the user for `poundsTotal` before the loop and once more at the end of the loop.

If you want to get really posh and do this without repeating code (and stay [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)) , make a function that gets `poundsTotal` from the user and call this function in the while loop's condition. For example,

```
while ((poundsTotal = getPoundsTotal()) >= 0)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: `do { ... } while (poundsTotal >= 0);` ought to work, right?

Comment: I wouldn't use `do`/`while` because by the point the program reaches the `while` It's done the bulk of the iteration computing with a negative `poundsTotal`. That seems wrong to me.